# Git, someone deleted my .git directory, and committed everything into a larger project that I don't want to start tracking locally

Tags: git

I've been working on a WordPress theme for a while, tracking it on my own repo back and forth, and pulling from the remote server through ssh.

Yesterday, someone from the company initialized the whole project tree as a repo, and deleted the `.git` directory of the directory I was working on.

Now, I have some new commits I want to take to the server, but the remote repository is now different than mine, and also other people have worked and made commits on the new (larger) repo.

What can I do in this situation in order to keep working only on the particular directory I was working on, and be able to synchronize my work correctly?

I have thought of two alternatives:

1.- Copy my `.git` directory into my working directory on the remote server. Then keep working as normal. 
2.- Start using `rsync` to move my changes onto the server.

I'm a bit lost here so any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your work tree is intact, you can try

Take a backup of your current clone / folder.

In current folder

```
 git init
```

Stash you changes and add your server remote as

```
 git remote add neo-origin ssh://example-server/project.git
```

Git fetch and checkout master (or whichever) branch relative to new-origin

Lastly apply the stash and push it to remote.